# Error serializing 'nested' JSON Object in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm deserializing the following JSON and having trouble with the categories/WebFilters section. I want to be able to loop through it but get the

> Cannot deserialize current JSON object into type - c#´
>
> CS1579    foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WebFilters' because 'WebFilters' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

error when I run my code. Eventually I need to make a list of the keys and values in each of the categories as I'm using it to create a dynamic results filter - I don't know at this stage what or how many filters they'll be.

I tried changing my json, but that doesn't achieve what I want it to. I think I need to give WebFilters the ability to be iterated over...

Thanks.

```
{
  "Webinars": [
    {
      "date":"2017-11-08T19:21:46Z",
      "title":"Americano",
      "desc":"Nondisp fx of prox phalanx of l mid fngr, 7thG",
      "startTime":"5:39 PM",
      "endTime":"5:19 PM",
      "categories":{
        "category":"introduction",
        "timeZone":"Europe/Stockholm",
        "language":"English"
      }
    },...
```

Model

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Webinar[] Webinars { get; set; }
    public ELearning[] ELearning { get; set; }
}

public class Webinar
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public WebFilters Categories { get; set; }
}

public class WebFilters
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@foreach (var webinar in Model.Webinars)
    {
       <li>@webinar.Title</li>
       <ul>
           @{ 
               var categories = webinar.Categories;
            }
            @foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                <li>@cat</li>
            }
       </ul>
    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Dashboard_Portal()
    {
        // Example JSON
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://elliottjbrown.co.uk/portal/js/data.json");
        var webinars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
        return View(webinars);
    }
```

Comment: See my updated post @Elliott.

Answer (score 2):

Your Categories Property in your Webinar class is not a collection of any kind, so you can't iterate over it.

You may be looking to either make it a collection:

`public WebFilters Categories[] { get; set; }` or
`public WebFilters List<Categories> { get; set; }`

If you actually want a collection of categories, you'll either need to have a partial view configured to render a given Category object, or you'll need to provide specific rendering inside your for loop. Something like this (note the below code will only show the one property):

```
@foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                <li>@cat.Category</li>
            }
```

If you only expect one category for each webinar, then you'll need to refer to each property individually in the View. Here's a .NET Fiddle showing a simple render with Categories as a single object, rather than a collection [Simple Display Render With Non-Collection Categories Property](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cfr1WH)

```
<ul>
    <li>@webinar.Categories.Category</li>
    <li>@webinar.Categories.TimeZone</li>
    <li>@webinar.Categories.Language</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a link to a .NET fiddle that shows what this might look like if you're just trying to iterate through the Categories and display them: [Simple Display Render With Category Collection](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjhZya). You'll notice that the `Webinars` and `Elearning` properties of the `Rootobject` are still arrays (not `List<T>`), as originally defined, and the the `Rootobject` does not implement `IEnumerable` as was suggested in other answers. There's no need for those changes.

Now, if you're looking for an ***edit page*** of some kind where the user can actually select a single category from a list of options, that's a different issue and wasn't clear from your OP.

Comment: I think I Do want to make it a collection. That code doesn't work though.  I'm using System.Collections.Generic but it's saying unexpected use of a generic term

Comment: @Elliott - Which code doesn't work? The code at the bottom of my example for the view would be if you wanted to use the Categories property as it already is. Are you expecting a Webinar to potentially have more than one Category?

Comment: @Elliott - I updated the above answer to give a very simple example of what the code might look like in the View for using a collection.

Comment: Thanks Steve. No, I'm not expecting the webinar to have more than one category, but I am unsure of how many categories, categories will contain. This is why I want to be able to iterate over my json object 'categories' and return its content. It works in both Javascript and PHP, unfortunately I have to to use C# for this so I'm kind of stuck!

Comment: @Elliott - I'm uncertain as to what you're modeling then. With your current code. The model you've created places Categories as a property of the Webinar. That translates to saying "These are the categories associated with THIS webinar.". That's also what your view is modeling. Are you trying to render a list of categories for the user to select one and assign it to the Webinar, or are you trying to model a display that shows what category/categories are already assigned to the webinar in question?

Comment: See my updated post @Steve Brouillard. Just tried to make it work. By the way, this isn't going to work - `@webinar.Categories.TimeZone` and will have compilation error.

Comment: @AT-2017 - If you follow the link, it leads to a work .NET Fiddle, complete with compiling code and an MVC page output. Not sure what you did to get a compile error. The example that you claim doesn't work was (as said in the description) intended to show how you might access each property directly ***if the OP wanted to use a single category***. The following fiddle shows it working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cfr1WH

Comment: I hope, you have already seen the raw `Json` data and IMO, the **Categories** shouldn't be defined as single item property as the **Categories** maintain a data structure called `array`. See this - `"categories": [{ "category": "e-learning", "timeZone": "Europe/Stockholm", "language": "German" }]`.

Comment: @AT-2017 I **did** see the JSON in the OP. However, your comment has the OP JSON wrong. Take another look. Cut and pasted from the original post, it is... `"categories":{
        "category":"introduction",
        "timeZone":"Europe/Stockholm",
        "language":"English"
      }`. Notice...braces only, no brackets. An object definition, ***not*** an array. That's why I presented the two options. I agree that it ***should*** be a collection. However, that's not how it was originally presented. That's why the original intent wasn't clear  and why I presented both options in my response.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the **Rootobject** class properties into `List<>` as follows:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Webinar> Webinars { get; set; }
}
```

**Update 1**:

**Note**: Make sure **Categories** in the **Webinar** class implements the `IEnumerable` interface or list collection as the `Json` data returns an array.

**Update 2**: I've updated your code and made it work using the following:

**The Webinar Class**:

```
public class Webinar
{
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Desc { get; set; }
   public string StartTime { get; set; }
   public string EndTime { get; set; }
   public WebFilters[] Categories { get; set; } //Converted it into a collection
}
```

**The Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Dashboard_Portal()
{
  var webClient = new WebClient();
  var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://elliottjbrown.co.uk/portal/js/data.json");

  var webinars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

  return View(webinars);
}
```

Finally, **The View**:

```
@model DemoApp.Models.Rootobject

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>
    @foreach (var webinar in Model.Webinars)
    {
        <h3>@webinar.Title</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>@webinar.Categories[0].TimeZone</li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

See the output with a screenshot:

[image: Json Object Deserialization]

Comment: In the same time, you don't have to iterate the `Catogories` object using `foreach`. Simply you can write **@webinar.Categories.TimeZone**.

Comment: I'm not at all sure how this addresses the issue. The OP is enumerating over the Webinars property, which is already an IEnumerable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/). He then tries to enumerate over the Categories Property, which is not. How will changing the arrays to List<T> address that issue? Also, he's not enumerating over the Rootobject, so having it implement IEnumerable still won't address that issue. He's not enumerating over the Rootobject anywhere.

Comment: See my answer for a .NET Fiddle link that allows iteration through the 'Categories' without changing the types of the properties or implementing `IEnumerable` on `Rootobject`. He's only need to implement `IEnumerable` on `Rootobject` if `Rootobject` represented some kind of collection itself, which it doesn't.

Comment: I can see that and never mind. **Categories** require a `List<T>` collection as the `Json` data returns an array.

Comment: I don't understand the insistence on converting the `Webinars` property to `List<T>`. There's nothing explicitly wrong with using either collection type (an array *or* a `List<T>`). Either one will generate a JSON array when serialized, and either can be enumerated over. I happen to prefer generic lists, but there's no reason that the solution requires it. I used the arrays in my solution because those were the types the OP uses. Your View also still refers to the properties directly, just as an indexed array, so that still doesn't iterate over the collection of `Categories'.

Comment: This is great, thank you! My insistence on iterating over the categories of each webinar is so that I don't have to explicitly declare every 'category' within categories. Your way gives me access to the data, but what if the categories have the potential to change? I.e, what if some data sources have a unique category/filter the others don't? As I said, my goal with this is a dropdown filter of all of the categories. In the same way clothes websites have a filter system. For an eaxample this is the php version I got working -. [PHP MockUp](http://elliottjbrown.co.uk/portal)

Answer (score -2):

according to [JSON-RPC spec](http://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-1-1-alt.html#service-procedure-and-parameter-names) , json is case senitive.

all of your c# class properties start with uppercases, but your json propertise with lowercases.

Comment: Because the OP is using ASP.NET Web API or MVC, the built in serializer in the model binder addresses that issue, either implicitly or explicitly (depending on the binding direction, version of MVC, and other code that may not be presented here).